# Update Query clearing results through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm developing under my development machine in PHP and connecting to the database remotly. I uploaded the files to the server and online the query works as expected but in localhost it doesn't. All other queries work!

I have a block of code to insert a new record at the database or update if it already exists.

The code is:

```
            $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['name']);
            $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['title']);
            $content = $_REQUEST['content'];
    $lang_drop = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['lang']);
            if($uid == 0)
            {
                $maxSort = tools::getInfo($table, Array(), Array('MAX(sort_order) as sort_order'));
                $maxSort = $maxSort[0]['sort_order']+1;
                    $sql="insert into quemsomos (title,name,lang,sort_order)
                            values(
                                '$title',
                                '$name',
                                '$lang_drop',
                                $maxSort
                            )";
                        echo $sql;
                    mysql_query($sql);
                    $uid = mysql_insert_id();
            }
            else{
$maxSort = $data['sort_order'];
                    $sql="update `quemsomos` set `title`='blabkalm', `name`='{$name}', `lang`='{$lang_drop}', `sort_order`=$maxSort where `uid`={$uid}";
                    mysql_query($sql);
                    echo $sql;
                }
```

Pretty simple... If I insert a new record it works fine and $sql value printed is:

```
insert into quemsomos (title,name,lang,sort_order) values('title412', 'name421', 'pt', 3 )
```

The problem is that when I update the query executes but only the hardcoded values are stored in database. I mean, after the bellow update all values in the DB are empty except for sort_order which is saved and title (because it's hardcoded... if i place the right variable the field gets blank also)

echo $sql for the update statement returns the following:

```
update `quemsomos` set `title`='blabkalm', `name`='name421', `lang`='pt', `sort_order`=3 where `uid`=2
```

As you can see all values are there and if I run this query manually all works out fine...

Does this make sense to anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this part

```
`uid`={$uid}";
```

is not okay. You can be very sure like this:

```
$sq='\''; 
$sql="update `quemsomos` set `title`='blabkalm', `name`=".$sq.$name.$sq.", `lang`=".$sq.
$lang_drop.$sq.", `sort_order`=".$sq.$maxSort.$sq." where `uid`=".$sq.$uid.$sq."   ";
```

This must work.

An other thing.. mysql error can help a lot in debugging cause output the error, don't forget to use it:

```
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Hi!! Thanks for the reply. I can only give it a try on monday... Although I never had to do that, right now I believe in everything ;) i'll get back to you! thanks